# IntelliJ hotswap notification off

Tags: intellij-idea, notifications, ide, hotswap

I changed my IDE Eclipse to IntelliJ and everything is good except one thing.
I use hotswap by adding springboot dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

But the problem is IntelliJ shows a notification continuously that tells me "Loaded classes are up to date nothing to reload". It is really annoying. Please let me know how to turn off that notification. I think the posted picture below will show the problem well.
Thank you so much.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Do you use [Spring Boot Debug Configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-spring-boot.html#configuration-tab)? You can set updating classes and resources only on explicit action with the Run/Debug Configurations -> **On frame deactivation** set to `Do nothing`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But the problem is not solved. If I changed "Do nothing" as you said, the hot swap is not working. The jsp source is not changed in time.

Comment: Added a bounty because I'm getting this problem as well when running the JBoss server, everytime Intellij loses focus, there's the notification and the taskbar blinking requesting focus. And no matter with you turn off hotswap notifications, or turn off ballon notifications, or turn off system notifications... And there's no answer for this in the intellij forums as well. Any ideas? Someone?

Answer (score 0):

Change the **Popup type** value in settings:

**Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> Notifications -> HotSwap**

[image]

Comment: I tried every change in this option, every type, and also disabling everything. Still the same.